# Frames of SKShapeNode children give false location

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, rotation

I have an SKShapeNode which has multiple SKSpriteNodes as its children, which are positioned around its center in various places. I also rotate that SKShapeNode, which in effect rotates all of its children. However, when I loop through all of those children and draw circles on locations of their frames, they are all drawn in the bottom left of the screen (offset by a large distance from where the sprites are actually drawn).

```
let Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 110)
Circle.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
Circle.name = "maincircle"

var tmpNode: SKSpriteNode


tmpNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: fallingObjects[0])
tmpNode.name = "blue_hvat"
tmpNode.setScale(0.1)
tmpNode.position = CGPointMake(0, 80)   
Circle.addChild(tmpNode)

tmpNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: fallingObjects[1])
tmpNode.name = "green_hvat"
tmpNode.setScale(0.1)
tmpNode.position = CGPointMake(0, -80)
Circle.addChild(tmpNode)

...

self.addChild(Circle)

...

guard let obj = self.childNodeWithName("maincircle") else {
    return
}
for l in (obj.children) {
    //here when I use l.frame I get the wrong location of those sprites
    continue
}
```

I browsed stackoverflow and found similar questions, but none of them helped me. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: how about showing the code that actually reproduces you problem and showing some results,  I see nothing wrong here, your frame should be showing position based on scene coordinates,  how do you know they are wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x position of all the children of your object is 0. So when you tried to draw circles at the position of their frame, they are all drawn at the bottom left of the screen, it's normal because in SpriteKit, the origin of the screen is the bottom left corner and because all the objects frames are relative to their parents.

So, if you have a parent that have an `x position` of `250`, and inside this parent, you have a node with an `x position` of `0`, the position of this child node is 0 related to his parent, but 250 related to the screen.

If you want to get the related to the screen position of the children of your `obj` node, I recommend you to proceed like this for example :

```
l.frame.origin.x + obj.frame.origin.x
l.frame.origin.y + obj.frame.origin.y
```

Comment: Is not a good idea, to get absolute coordinate reference to the scene, is better to use convertPoint func. With this function, does not matter the children tree order